# "Remove" icon and center align text in listview via css

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Here's an example of a very simple jquery-mobile page with a list view widget.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scaleable=no"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">

  .ui-listview .ui-btn-inner {
    text-align: center;
  }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="main_page" >

  <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
     <p><center>+</center></p> 
  </div>

    <div data-role="content" >

    <ul id="test" data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
      <li><a href="#" data-transition="slide">Heading 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-transition="slide">Heading 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-transition="slide">Heading 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-transition="slide">Heading 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

A listview normally displays each link as text left aligned along with an arrow icon which is right aligned. I've hidden the icon by choosing data-icon="false" and center aligned the text via css. However, the icon is still taking up some space in the button and the text is therefore not perfectly aligned within the button. How can I solve this? I tried setting the icon width to zero but that made no difference.

[Online example](http://www.parma.se/iphone3/test.html)

Comment: `$('.ui-li-has-arrow ').removeClass('ui-li-has-arrow ');` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/e2fAa/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your list items have a css class called "ui-li-has-arrow" – this is adding padding-right: 40px to the links, pushing them to the left.

You can override this in the head of test.html.

Where you currently have:

```
<style type="text/css">

.ui-listview .ui-btn-inner {
  text-align: center;
}

</style>
```

Change it to:

```
<style type="text/css">

.ui-listview .ui-btn-inner {
  text-align: center;
}
.ui-li-has-arrow .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li-has-arrow {
  padding-right: 15px;
}


</style>
```